# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 63: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, email, utf-8

So I am trying to download a batch of emails for a friend that set up a webform that sent responses from a survey directly to their email rather than into a spreadsheet. The issue I am running into is that I can get all of one type of response, the people signing up to act as mentors, but none of the other responses, those that wish to be mentees. When I try to download any emails from mentee applicants I get the following error:

```
$ ./Email_Get_0.1.py 
Do you want to search for Mentor or Mentee forms? (enter: Mentor / Mentee) 
mentee
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tmac/Programing/AccelAi/Mentor-Matching/Email Script/./Email_Get_0.1.py", line 75, in <module>
    download_emails(MENTEE)
  File "/Users/tmac/Programing/AccelAi/Mentor-Matching/Email Script/./Email_Get_0.1.py", line 64, in download_emails
    output_file.write("Date: %s\n\nBody: \n\n%s" %(local_message_date, body.decode('utf-8')))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 63: invalid continuation byte
```

Any idea what is missing here, why it works for mentors but not mentees, or what I can do to get around this and get these emails downloaded? Thanks for the help!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Access email and get contents to csv """
import email, datetime, imaplib, os, re, html2text

# Credentials to log into gmail and search for specific labels
EMAIL_UN = '######################'
EMAIL_PW = '#######################'
MENTOR = 'Form Submission - Mentor Application'
MENTEE = 'Form Submission - Mentee Application'

# Current directory to save the text files
cwd = os.getcwd()
# Start date of current mentorship applicant pool, can be adjusted for follow on uses
sentSince = "SENTSINCE 01-Jan-2022"

def download_emails(SUBJECT):
    un = EMAIL_UN
    pw = EMAIL_PW
    url = 'imap.gmail.com'
    # Folder is the inbox document tree with custom label
    folder = "\"" + "Mentoring Program" + "\""
    complexSearch = sentSince + " Subject " + "\"" + SUBJECT + "\""
    detach_dir = cwd # directory where to save attachments (default: current)
    # connecting to the gmail imap server
    m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(url,993)
    m.login(un,pw)
    m.select(folder)

    # # This allows us to cycle through the folders and labels in gmail to find what we need
    # for items in m.list('/'):
    #     for item in items:
    #         print(item)
    
    resp, items = m.search(None, complexSearch)
    # you could filter using the IMAP rules here (check http://www.example-code.com/csharp/imap-search-critera.asp)
    
    items = items[0].split() # getting the mails id

    for emailid in items:
        resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)") # fetching the mail, "`(RFC822)`" means "get the whole stuff", but you can ask for headers only, etc
        if resp != 'OK':
            raise Exception("Error reading email: {}".format(data))
        raw_email = data[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

        # Header Details
        date_tuple = email.utils.parsedate_tz(email_message['Date'])
        if date_tuple:
            local_date = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(email.utils.mktime_tz(date_tuple))
            local_message_date = "%s" %(str(local_date.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")))
            email_from = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['From'])))
            email_to = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['To'])))
            subject = str(email.header.make_header(email.header.decode_header(email_message['Subject'])))

        # Body details
        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_type() == "text/plain":
                body = part.get_payload(decode=True)
                file_name = subject + "_" + local_message_date + ".txt"
                output_file = open(file_name, 'w')
                output_file.write("Date: %s\n\nBody: \n\n%s" %(local_message_date, body.decode('latin-1')))
                output_file.close()
    
            else:
                continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    download = input("Do you want to search for Mentor or Mentee forms? (enter: Mentor / Mentee) \n")
    if download.upper() == 'MENTOR':
        download_emails(MENTOR)
    elif download.upper() == 'MENTEE':
        download_emails(MENTEE)
    else:
        print('Usage: ./download_emails.py @ prompt enter Mentor or Mentee:')
```

Comment: Can you include the full traceback in the post?

Comment: Absolutely, sorry about that!

Comment: By calling `.decode("utf-8")` you assume that the email was encoded with UTF-8, but apparently this is not the case. I presume (or hope!) that some email metadata tell you which character set was used to encode the message. But I'm absolutely no expert in email format and can't tell you where to look or which tools to use, I'm afraid.